# C : how to to execute remotely a command line programm and interact with it from a server?

Tags: c, server, tcp, client

I made a simple tcp client in C (in windows I precise), which is controlled by netcat. I would like to be able to run a command line executable (such as Strings for example) remotely, and above all to be able to interact from netcat or my server with this programme.( (in order to perform actions on the remote computer in particular).

What would be the best solution to do that ?

edit : Here is an example : I want to run String programm on the remote computer. To do that, I can simply write "string" in netcat, this command would be interpreted by client, and this client execute strings binary. The output of strings should be displayed on netcat.

I precise that the binary of the programm can be on the remote computer, but it would be great if there is a way to execute it as a "real" remote programm, without need to get the executable on the remote machine.

Comment: Do you want netcat to be able to run shell command, or your "simple tcp client"? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I just edit my question.

Comment: Then please tell us if this is only for learning and experimentation, and if not please tell us what problem you're trying to solve with remote command execution that existing systems (e.g. SSH) doesn't solve.

Comment: it is for a personal project that must be done without ssh indeed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your terminology is a bit off. You said you write a tcp client. But it seems you wrote a server. Because this programs should receive incoming tcp connection and request to then send responses.

In order to execute commands, you can use the `exec*` syscalls.
But then you would need to have the executables available in the machine.

Then you would need to build some for for loop around the tcp read that execute things for each line send, and a bit of setup to ensure that you redirect the output in the tcp connection. See the `dup`syscall.

Ultimately, if you do not want to write a full shell-like program, you could just `exec`the system shell (`cmd.exe` on windows I think), and redirect all inputs/output to it.

Comment: I just verified my answer, but indeed I wrote a tcp client, and not server, because my programm just connect to a specified adress with a specified port : my program does not wait for a connection, like a server does, but maybe my answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for these tips ,I will look for some informations about that.